# trying to facebook access token with curl and get error "missing authorization code "

Tags: php, facebook, curl

i have try to get Facebook access token with curl i have got this error 
"missing authorization code " 
this is my code

```
$curl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=myurl/fb-tokens/&client_secret=xxxx&amp;code=".$_GET['code']."";
        $crl = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$curl);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $ret = curl_exec($crl);
        curl_close($crl);
        $final_result = json_decode($ret);
        print_r($final_result);
```

can any body help me ?

Comment: does it work if you hardcode the `$code`? What do you get for `$_GET['code']` now? Does it maybe need to get `url_encode()`d?

Comment: this same url  i will copy and past in to browser this will give me access token but when i will try with  curl this will show error.

Comment: `&amp;` is HTML. This is not HTML.

Comment: And you should properly URL-encode the parameter values.

Comment: can any body help me ?